# Finding greatest fall and rise in a dynamic rolling window based on index

Tags: pandas

Have a df of readings as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=100), index=range(100), columns = ['reading'])
```

Want to find the greatest rise and the greatest fall for each row based on its index, which theoretically may be achieved using the formula...

[image]

How can this be coded?

Tried:

```
df.assign(gr8Rise=df.rolling(df.index).apply(lambda x: x[-1]-x[0], raw=True).max())
```

...and failed with `ValueError: window must be an integer`

UPDATE: Based on @jezrael dataset the output for gr8Rise is expected as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=10), index=range(10), columns = ['reading'])

df['gr8Rise'] = [df['reading'].rolling(x).apply(lambda x: x[0]-x[-1], raw=True).max() 
                 for x in range(1, len(df)+1)]
df.loc[0, 'gr8Rise']= np.nan
print (df)
   reading  gr8Rise
0       72      NaN
1       31     41.0
2       37     64.0
3       88     59.0
4       62     73.0
5       24     76.0
6       29     72.0
7       15     57.0
8       12     60.0
9       16     56.0
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't look to be correct. Row 1 should be 41, Row 2 should be 64. Please have a look at https://imgur.com/a/GrpAgE5?

Comment: df.gr8Rise.iloc[1] should be = 41 as 72 - 31 = 41 is the greatest rise.
df.gr8Rise.iloc[2] should be = 64 as 88 - 24 = 64 is the greatest rise.
Not able to understand how you got 51 and 51 for these...

Comment: @reservoirinvest - hmmm, so what is expected output for all data?

Comment: gr8Rise[0..9] = (41, 64, 59, 73, 76, 72, 57, 60, 56).

Comment: @reservoirinvest - thanks, how are counts last 2 values? Because `last` is not `29-72=-43` ?

Comment: please see UPDATE in the question.

Comment: @reservoirinvest - Is performance important? What is size of DataFrame?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203585/discussion-between-reservoirinvest-and-jezrael).

Comment: @reservoirinvest - You are welcome! Btw, Maybe if check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59172699/2901002) and compare with my solution above, it is question about improve performance of this solution ;)